# Cannot Get Import to Work with Subpackages

Tags: python, module, package

The following structure (in `Python 3.7`) is not allowing me to import class `A` in module `B`:

```
package:
    package:
        __init__.py
        a:
            __init__.py
            a.py
        b:
            __init__.py
            b.py
```

The top-level `__init__.py` is blank. Here are the remaining files:

**a**

```py
# package/package/a/__init__.py

from .a import A
```

```py
# package/package/a/a.py

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**b**:

```py
# package/package/b/__init__.py

from .b import B
```

```py
# package/package/b/b.py

from package.a.a import A

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Without doing anything else, on Windows, if I try to run `b.py` (from within the `b` folder), I get the following error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.a'
```

If I add a `main.py` at the top level:

```
package:
    package:
        __init__.py
        main.py
        a:
            __init__.py
            a.py
        b:
            __init__.py
            b.py
```

containing

```py
# package/package/main.py

import a
import b
```

and run `main.py` (from within `package/package`), I get the same error.

If I change `b.py` to

```py
# package/package/b/b.py

from ..a.a import A

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

and run `b.py` (from within the `b` folder) or `main.py` (from within `package/package`), I get the error that

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) make it seem like I should be able to do this though!

Can someone please explain why I am getting these errors? I've seen a couple similar posts to this, but they haven't fixed my problem:

1. [Importing Submodules Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572316/importing-submodules-python-3)
2. [Python submodule importing correctly in python 3.7 but not 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524794/python-submodule-importing-correctly-in-python-3-7-but-not-3-6)

Comment: You have a circular import.  `test.b.b` imports `test.a`, which then imports `test.a.a`, which then imports `test.b` which imports `test.b.b`, but it was being instantiated so an `ImportError` is triggered, which bubbles out to that `from test.a import A` statement and thus it is reported that `ModuleNotFoundError` for `test.a`. Specifically, the import here will access members that are not fully loaded, ultimately causing this `ImportError` See: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027011/resolve-circular-import-error-in-python) and its linked threads for additional information

Comment: @metatoaster I removed `from test.b import B` in `a.py` and still get the same error.

Comment: How and where are you running `b.py`? If this is just a random collection of directories (i.e. not a "proper" Python package) it will simply fail even if you are in the `Test` directory.  However you can temporarily workaround that by running `PYTHONPATH=. python test/b/b.py`, but this is not portable -  Ideally you will need to turn your directory structure into a package by including a [`setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py) and then install it into your Python environment, otherwise imports may simply not work as Python will not know how to import them.

Comment: @metatoaster I am running `b.py` in directory `b` by itself. I was doing this because I am still writing my code and am not ready to release yet. For development purposes, is it best practice to create a virtual environment with `pipenv`, write a `setup.py`, then `pipenv install` to that virtual environment? In general, is `setuptools` always required for this to work?

Comment: It is always best practice to set up your project as a package that may be installed into different Python environments such that it may be easier to test across multiple environments. `setuptools` make this task significantly easier but it is not strictly necessary - you always have the option to manually create the required metadata files necessary for Python to treat your project directory as a Python package (e.g. the `.egg-link` files inside a virtual environment `site-packages` for a dev package, along with a number of others like `PKGINFO`), but this manual process is not recommended.

Comment: Aside from `setuptools`, there are other much lesser known options for creating a package, but given the prevalence of `setuptools` it's best to stick with that while you are still learning.  Once you got this working, you should have no trouble importing your modules from your package from any working directory on your operating system/environment.

Comment: @metatoaster Agreed. Just to be clear though, is it true to say `setuptools` must be used? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages has not made this clear, at least to me. The docs (and several posts online) make it seem like all that is required are properly formed and placed `__init__.py` files within the project directory structure.

Comment: That page only gave a very high level overview as to the structure and other definitions of the import system, but not necessarily how to actually make it work.  Previously [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html#module-distutils) was created as the builtin option for creating packages, but as you can see even the official documentation now recommend the usage of `setuptools`.

Comment: @metatoaster I see. Okay, understood. Let me try this "practice project" again with a `setup.py` and answer the question. Or would you like to so I can credit you with the answer?

Comment: You could do a self-answer instead.  Best of luck.

Comment: @metatoaster Thank you! I've renamed `test` to `package`, so as not to confuse others (in case they think my code is related to unit tests), and further clarified my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever module is being run by Python is called **top-level**.

- In your shell, when you run `> py main.py` (`$ python3 main.py` on Linux), the file `main.py` is top-level and is called the **top-level module**.
- In the interpreter, the interpreter itself is always top-level, and is called the **top-level environment** (for proof, type `>>> __name__` into the interpreter and it will return `'__main__'`)

Unfortunately (IMO), the term "top-level" is not well-defined in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/__main__.html) as it is used in several different contexts. Regardless, it is important to understand that **Python always renames `__name__` of the top-level entity to `'__main__'`**.

[PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) (explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1)) states

> relative imports use the module's `__name__` attribute to determine its position in the package hierarchy.

Since Python renames the `__name__` of the top-level module to `'__main__'`, **the top-level module has no package information** because it has no dots in its name.

Hence, top-level modules are not considered part of any package (even though they very well may be!). In other words, for packages imported from the current directory, **`'__main__'` determines what is top-level**. Packages at the same level as `'__main__'` (`a` and `b` in my example) are top-level packages.

Confusingly, the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) and [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) give a misleading example. The "correct usages" shown for relative imports ***are only valid in a specific context*.**

Recall that `import` searches paths listed in `sys.path` to find packages and modules to import. The current directory is in `sys.path`, along with the paths to builtin packages (like `math` and `os`) and installed packages (i.e. `pip install`ed package). ***Python does not rename the `__name__` of non-top-level packages***.

Therefore, the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) and [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) examples are valid **only for packages and modules NOT in the top-level directory**.

What I should have written was `from a.a import A`:

```py
# package/package/b/b.py

from a.a import A

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Since `package` is above the top-level module, trying to do an absolute import (like `from package.a.a import a`) results in an `ImportError` even though `main.py` is inside of the package `package`.

That being said, if you go to PyPI and GitHub and look at released packages, you will find they have absolute imports like `import package.a.a`! In fact, if I were to publish my package and leave the import as `from a.a import A`, end users would get an `ImportError` because they installed package `package` and don't have a package `a`! Furthermore, in the current configuration, I'm unable to test with `unittest` or `pytest` that users can import and use my package as expected because I cannot do `from package.a.a import A` myself!

***So the question becomes how do you write and test your own custom packages?***

The trick is that these packages were written in **development mode**. To install your package in development mode, run `> pip install -e .` from the top-level directory (assuming you have a `setup.py` written; see the **NOTE** below).

When this is done, python treats your package like a typical library package (i.e. a `pip install`ed package), so python does not change its `__name__` to `__main__`. Thus, you can

- import it with absolute imports
- test and use your package like an end user would, and
- any edits you make to it take effect immediately when run without requiring you re-`pip install` it, just like packages in the top-level directory do

This key difference between developing packages vs. standalone programs is a huge source of confusion and frustration for most first-time developers (myself included) and is very important to keep in mind. I hope this answer provides clarification for others and may be added to documentation in the future. Please let me know in the comments below if this helped you.

**NOTE:** `pip install -e .`, where `-e` stands for "editable", puts a link (a `*.pth` file) in your python installation folder so that the package is treated as an installed package, but also that any changes you write in it will take effect immediately (see the [Python Packaging Tutorial](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html)). Hence, you can use this to develop your own packages or to install and edit third-part packages to your needs. This requires you create a `setup.py`, but all your test code, client code, etc., will be able to import your package the usual way (i.e. you can treat your package like any other `pip install`ed package). You can achieve the same effect with `poetry` and `flit` by configuring your `pyproject.toml` file.

Here are some additional useful references:

1. [realpython.com: Python Modules and Packages - An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)
2. [realpython.com: Python import: Advanced Techniques and Tips](https://realpython.com/python-import/)
3. [realpython.com: Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

Comment: It's possible to make unit tests that use relative imports (`..package.a.a`), but the tests need to be inside the package dir (`package/tests`) and the tests must be started from the *parent* of the package dir (`package/../`). It's also likely possible to use absolute imports in this case.

Comment: @Ark-kun Yes, this is a case where the `src` file layout would be used. Completely valid, I agree. I personally prefer to keep the `tests` folder outside the package though.